# Pushing to remote fails because "tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart"

Tags: git, github, rebase

[image: terminal commands and output duplicated below, showing git pull, rebase and push ultimately failing to to the tip of the branch being behind]

```sh
$ git config pull.ff only
$ git pull
Already up to date
$ git checkout EditReadMe1
Switched to branch 'EditReadMe2'
$ git rebase master
Current branch EditReadMe2 is up to date
$ git push myremote EditReadMe2
To https://github.com/[redacted repo]-playground
 ! [rejected]         EditReadMe2 -> EditReadMe2 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/[redacted repo]-playground'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: it's remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

My friend is trying to help me learn to resolve conflicts in pull requests. He created a repository. I cloned it, and created a branch called "EditReadMe2". I pushed "EditReadMe2" to the repository, and he created a conflict.

I originally ran the following commands

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout EditReadMe2
git rebase master
```

It warned me of a conflict which I resolved, but when I tried pushing EditReadMe2 it gave me the error.

I entered in the commands again to show my terminal in the attached image, because I don't know how its possible for the branch to be behind when I pull and rebase a second time, and it tells me everything is up to date, but then it still fails.

Force pushing solved the problem, but I want to know how to do this without using `--force`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command sequence is incomplete.
After `git checkout EditReadMe2` you need to perform another `git pull`.

`git pull` updates the working index of the current branch, not of all ***local*** branches you have.
When you issue the rebase command, you are rebasing an updated `master` into your "old" `EditReadMe2` branch.

Anyway the `git rebase` is fine to be used in such way.

---

An hint:
if you are switching to `master`, `git pull`ing, switching back to `EditReadMe2` **only** for the purpouse of rebasing, you can use the following sequence and save a couple of commands:

Assuming you are in `EditReadMe2`

```
git pull
git rebase origin/master
```

Answer (score 3):

Rebasing will typically produce this result—this need to use `--force`—because rebasing *replaces* some existing commit(s) with new-and-improved<sup>1</sup> commits.  To really understand how this works, you need to understand how Git uses and finds commits, and how `git push` and other commands work.  It's a little bit tricky!  First, take a look at [my long answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62626841/1256452) to [How to delete all unpushed commits without deleting local changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62623285/1256452), to get an idea of what a drawing like:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

might mean.  In particular, you need to remember how these letters stand in for the raw hash IDs, how each commit points backwards to its parent commit, and how a branch name points to the *latest* commit on / contained-in that branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>At least, we *hope* they're improved.

---

#### Setting up

Now let's suppose we have a series of commits that's not *flawed* per se—we don't really need to fix anything in them—but which were made earlier, like this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature
```

(no attached `HEAD` indicates that we don't care which one was checked out before this point).  We run `git checkout master` or `git switch` master, then `git pull` or similar, and acquire a new `master` commit, giving us this:

```
...--G--H--K   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature, origin/feature
```

We also add or update these *remote-tracking names*, `origin/master` and `origin/feature`.  They are our Git's memory of some *other* Git's *branch* names.  Our name `origin/master` identifies commit `K`, as does our own branch name `master` now; and our name `origin/feature` tells us that over on `origin`, they have a copy of our branch name `feature` that identifies commit `J` too, just like our `feature`.  (Perhaps they got it when, earlier, we ran `git push origin feature`.)

This next part is important: **The commit hash IDs—the big ugly strings of letters and digits that these uppercase letters stand in for—are *the same* across both repositories.**  The branch names need not be, although in this particular case, they are as well, right now.

#### Rebase works by copying commits

In this setup, we decide that the flaw with our feature is that it's based on commit `H`, when the latest commit is now commit `K`.  We'd like to have our `feature` branch based on commit `K`.  To do that, we run:

```
git switch feature       # or git checkout feature
```

giving us:

```
...--G--H--K   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature (HEAD), origin/feature
```

followed by:

```
git rebase master
```

The rebase command lists out the raw hash IDs of those commits that are on branch `feature` but *are not* on `master`.  In this case, that is the hash IDs of commits `I` and `J`.  (Note that commits `H` and earlier are on *both* branches.)  Then, Git uses its special "detached HEAD" mode to start working with commit `K`, at the tip of `master`:

```
...--G--H--K   <-- HEAD, master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature, origin/feature
```

Git applies what we did in commit `I` and makes a new commit from it.  This new commit has a new, different hash ID, but re-uses the author name and date-and-time-stamps from `I`, and re-uses the commit message from `I`, so that the commit looks an awful lot like commit `I`.  In other words, it's a *copy* of commit `I`.<sup>2</sup>  We'll call this new copy `I'`:

```
             I'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--G--H--K   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature, origin/feature
```

Having successfully copied `I` to `I'`, Git now copies `J` the same way, resulting in:

```
             I'-J'  <-- HEAD
            /
...--G--H--K   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- feature, origin/feature
```

The copying process is now done—there are no more commits to copy—so rebase executes its final step, which is to yank the name `feature` off the commit it used to name and make it point to the last-copied commit, in this case `J'`:

```
             I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--G--H--K   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/feature
```

As the drawing implies, in this last step, Git re-attaches `HEAD` so that we're back in the normal mode of working with an attached `HEAD`, being on the branch.

Note that the two original commits here are no longer findable using the name `feature`.  If we did not have the name `origin/feature` remembering the *other* Git's `feature`, we would have abandoned these two commits entirely.  But our Git remembers that *their* Git remembers commit `J` using *their* name `feature`.

In either case, note what we have done.  **We threw out, or at least tried to throw out, the old commits in favor of these new and improved ones.**  We still have access to the old commits through our `origin/feature` name, because we're remembering that the Git over on `origin` is remembering commit `J` through *its* branch name `feature`.

---

<sup>2</sup>You can, if you like, copy any commit yourself using `git cherry-pick`.  What `rebase` does is to detach your HEAD, then do an automated set of cherry-picks, followed by this branch-name motion, similar to `git reset` or `git branch -f`.  In older version of Git, rebase can default to an alternate strategy that does not literally run `git cherry-pick`, but these details don't usually matter.

---

#### How `git push` works

The `git push` command works by having your Git call up some other Git.  This other Git has commits and branch names, too.  Their branch names need not match your branch names, but if they don't, things get pretty confusing, so most people make their branch names the same here.

Their Git lists out, for your Git, *their* branch names and commit hash IDs.<sup>3</sup>  This lets your Git figure out which commits you have that they don't, that they'll need.  Your Git then sends those commits to their Git, by their hash IDs.  Along with those commits, your Git sends any other internal objects their Git requires.

Having sent the right objects, your Git now sends along one or more polite requests or commands.  The polite requests have this form: *Please, if it's OK, set your name ______ (fill in a branch or tag name) to ______ (fill in a hash ID).*  The commands have one of two forms: *I think your name ______ (fill in a branch or tag name) is set to ______ (fill in a hash ID). If so, set it to ______!*  Or: *Set your name ______ to ______!*

The polite request form will *ask* them to set their `feature` to point to commit `J'`, our copy of `J` that we used as a new-and-improved version of `J`.  ***They*, however, have no idea that this is meant to be a new-and-improved copy—all they can tell is that we're asking them to *throw out* commits `I` and `J`, and make their name `feature` remember commit `J'` instead.  They say *no!***  They say *If I do that, I will lose some commits.*

That's what we want them to do: lose commits `I` and `J`, replacing them with the new-and-improved ones.  To make them do that, we *must* send them a command.

If we use `git push --force-with-lease`, we'll send them that conditional command: *I think your `feature` identifies commit `J`; if so, make it identify `J'` instead.*  If they accept this command and do it, we and they will have commits `I'-J'` and we can draw our repository like this now:

```
             I'-J'  <-- feature (HEAD), origin/feature
            /
...--G--H--K   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   [abandoned]
```

**This `--force-with-lease` option is generally the right way to do this *if* it's allowed to do this at all.**  Doing this forces anyone else who is using the `feature` branch, in yet another Git repository, to update *their* branches using the new-and-improved commits.  In general, it's a good idea to get everyone to agree that `feature` might be rebased this way, before you start rebasing it this way.  What you need to do is figure out who "everyone" is.  If that's just yourself, you need only agree with yourself.  If that's you and six co-workers, get agreement from the co-workers first.

Using `git push --force`, instead of `--force-with-lease`, omits the safety check: it just sends to the other Git the command *set your `feature`* without any conditional "I think" part first.  If your Git is up to date with their Git, so that your `origin/feature` and their `feature` both identify commit `J`, this is OK.  But what if, just after you finished your work and were about to push, *someone else* added a new commit `L` to the `feature` in the Git over on `origin`?  Your force-push will tell that Git to abandon *that* commit, too.

The force-with-lease option is better because your Git will say to the other Git that you believe their `feature` identifies commit `J`, not commit `L`.  They'll say: Whoops, no, mine is now `L` and your `git push --force-with-lease` will fail.  You can now `git fetch`, see that there's a new commit `L`, and fix up your rebase to copy commit `L` too, then try your `git push --force-with-lease` again now that your `origin/feature` says commit `L`.

---

<sup>3</sup>The exact mechanism here was rewritten for Git smart protocol v2, which was first turned by default in Git 2.26.  I won't go into details, but there's a small but nasty little bug in early v2 protocols where your Git can push way too many objects sometimes.  This bug is fixed in Git 2.27.  If you have 2.26 and pushes are taking much too long, you can work around it with `git -c protocol.version=0 push ...`, or just upgrade.